# Prime number Determinants

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I have come up this final result after deriving some prime-related equations.
Let $m,s,P$, be an integers, and $P = 6k+1, k>0$. Let $m^2 = 9s^2 + P$, then $P$ is prime iff $\forall s, -k<s<k$, there is no integer solution for $m$. Alternatively, if there exists at least one integer $s, -k<s<k$, so that $m$ is an integer, then $P$ is nonprime. Can someone verify this result if I am correct or not?

Comment: What are you asking?

Comment: Let m,s,P, be an integers, and P = 6k+1, k>0. Let m² = 9s² + P, then P is prime iff ∀s, -k<s<k, there is no integer solution for m. Alternatively, if there exists at least one integer s, -k<s<k, so that m is an integer, then P is nonprime. Can someone verify this result?

Comment: Why not edit the body of your Question with that clarification,  rather than posting the Comment above?  There are further improvements to be made, such as explaining how it applies in a particular case or what makes this a "result" as opposed to a conjecture.

Comment: hi, i repost my question in comment because my question is not fully shown on the main body, i don't know why it is not showing (when i edit it, the question is in its entirety but still not showing in full after savng edits.

Comment: You had a `<` outside a MathJax environment. Thus the parser interpreted it as opening a HTML tag (invalid, of course), which caused the following part not to be rendered. I've edited and placed everything that should be into a MathJax environment.

Comment: thank you very much Daniel.

Comment: In the expression for $m$, $s$ is squared so you need only check $0 \le s \lt k$.

Comment: Yes Peter that is correct but i just included the (-k,k) as it is required on my original result.

Comment: Assume $m^2 = 9s^2 + P$ holds with integers $m$ and $s$. We can assume $m, s$ both non-negative. Rearranging yields the factorisation $P = (m - 3s)(m + 3s)$. If $P$ is prime, then we must have $m - 3s = 1$, and hence $P = 1\cdot (1 + 6s)$, which means $s = k$. So it remains to see that if $P$ is composite, such a factorisation, with $1 < m - 3s$ and $0 \leqslant s < k = (P -1)/6$ always exists.

Comment: thanks Daniel for the answer, but s<k, as required above. Another example here: if k = 9 then s ={0,1,2,...,8}, let us exclude those negative intgers for now as suggested by Peter Phipps. Since 6*9+1 = 55 nonprime, then there exists at least one integer s, here s =1, so that m² = 9(1)² + 55 = 64, hence m = ± 8. So in essence, if P is nonprime there is always at least one integer s that makes m an integer, else P is prime.

Comment: the reason why s≠k because if s = k, then m² = 9s² + 6s +1 =9k² + 6k +1, which becomes m² = (3s+1)² or m = 3s+1 for all s =k, and that includes those k that makes 6k +1 nonprimes. That is why we restrict  0≤s<k.